# Trying to save dataframe when button is clicked in different "IF" cases R

Tags: r, shiny

Eg: I want to save the filtered_output on every if cases after the user click on the button. What's happening is if user select Average for one row, data changes but, after that user selects min or average for another row the data the goes missing from the first click. It shows the df() data again.

```
  filtered_output <- df()
```

=====Button Event ========================

```
 observeEvent(input$confirm_numeric_replace, {

    if(input$select_numeric_replace_with == "Average"){
      filtered_output <- filtered_output() %>% mutate_at(vars(input$select_numeric_replace_input), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .x))
        output$filtered_table <- renderDataTable(filtered_output)
    }
    if(input$select_numeric_replace_with == "Min"){ 
        filtered_output <- filtered_output() %>% mutate_at(vars(input$select_numeric_replace_input), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), min(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .x))
        output$filtered_table <- renderDataTable(filtered_output)
    }
    if(input$select_numeric_replace_with == "Max"){ 
        filtered_output <- filtered_output() %>% mutate_at(vars(input$select_numeric_replace_input), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), max(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .x))
        output$filtered_table <- renderDataTable(filtered_output)
    }
    if(input$select_numeric_replace_with == "0"){
        filtered_output <- filtered_output() %>% mutate_at(vars(input$select_numeric_replace_input), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), 0, .x))
        output$filtered_table <- renderDataTable(filtered_output)
    }


})
```

---

The full code is below.

```
 library(shinydashboard)
 library(fontawesome)
 library(thematic)
 library(DT)
 library(dplyr)


dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(),
dashboardSidebar(),
dashboardBody()
)

 ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(dropdownMenu(type = "messages",
                             messageItem(from = "Sales Dept",
                                         message = "Message from Sales"),
                             messageItem(from = "New User",
                                         message = "Message from new user",
                                         icon = icon("question"))
                             ),#closing dropdownmenu for message
                dropdownMenu(type = "notification",
                             notificationItem(text = "12 items deliverd",
                                              icon = icon("truck")),
                             notificationItem(text = "5 new users",
                                              icon = icon("users"))
                             ),#closing Notification drop down
                dropdownMenu(type = "tasks", badgeStatus = "success",
                             taskItem(value = 90, color = "green", "Documentation")
                             )
                ),#closing dashboard header
dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
        menuItem("Cleaning", tabName = "cleaning", icon = icon("th")),
        menuItem("Graphs", tabName = "graphs",  icon =icon(name = "signal", class = NULL, lib = "font-awesome") ),
        menuItem(tabName = "Analysis", "analyse", icon =icon(name = "diagnoses", class = NULL, lib = "font-awesome"))

    )
),
dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
        # First tab content
        tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",


                fluidRow(
                    fileInput("filename", "", accept = c(".csv",".tsv"))
                ),
                fluidRow(
                    column(12,
                           dataTableOutput("main_file"))
                )

        ),#Tab Dashboard

        # Second tab content
        tabItem(tabName = "cleaning",
                uiOutput("omitna"),
                fluidRow(


                    column(2,
                           "Type numeric column name to replace NA with.",
                           selectInput("select_numeric_replace_input", "Replace NA in the column", c(""))
                    ),
                    column(3,
                           tags$br(),tags$br(),
                           selectInput("select_numeric_replace_with", "Replace NA in column with", c("Average", "Minimun", "Max", "0")))
                ),
                fluidRow(column(2,
                                actionButton("confirm_numeric_replace","Replace NA"),
                                uiOutput("button_press")
                )
                ), 
                fluidRow(

                    tags$br(),tags$br(),
                    column(2,
                           "Type categorical column name to replace NA with.",
                           selectInput("select_cat_replace_input", "Replace NA in the column with", c(""))
                    ),
                    column(3,
                           tags$br(),tags$br(),tags$br(),
                           textInput("select_cat_replace_with", "Replace NA in column with")),
                ),
                fluidRow(column(2,
                                actionButton("confirm_cat_replace","Replace NA")
                )
                ),
                fluidRow(tags$br(), tags$br(), column(2,
                                "Convert data type of the Row",
                                selectInput("label_data_type_replace", "Convert column type", c("Rows"))
                                ),
                        column(3,
                               "Convert data type to",
                               selectInput("select_data_type_replace", "Convert data type of", c("Numeric","Character","Date"))
                               )
                         ),
                fluidRow(column(2,
                               actionButton("confirm_dt_convert","Convert Data Type"))
                ),
                fluidRow(
                    tags$br(),
                    column(12,
                           dataTableOutput("filtered_table"))
                ),
                fluidRow(
                    tags$br(),
                    column(12,
                           tableOutput("missing_summary"))
                )

        ),#Tabitem Widgets

        #Graphs tab content
        tabItem(tabName = "graphs",
                fluidRow("Graphs")
                ),#tabitem Graphs

        #Tab Analyse
        tabItem(tabName = "analyse",
                fluidRow(

                )#Fluidrow
                )#tabitem Analyse
    )
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { 

df <- reactive(pokemon)
#############################DashBoard######
# df <- reactive({
#     req(input$filename)
#     
#     ext <- tools::file_ext(input$filename$name)
#     switch (
#         ext,
#         csv = vroom::vroom(input$filename$datapath, delim = ","),
#         tsv = vroom::vroom(input$file$datapath, delim = "\t"),
#         validate("Invalid file; Please upload a .csv or .tsv file")
#     )
# })

output$main_file <- renderDataTable(df())
#closing Dashboard

#Cleaning######################################
output$omitna <- renderUI(selectInput("omitna","Remove columns which has NA or no data in the file.",c("Don't change","Remove_Columns")))
filtered_output <- reactive(if(input$omitna == "Remove_Columns"){

    filtered_output <- (na.omit(df()))
}else {filtered_output <- df()}
)


observe({
    num_col <- names(dplyr::select_if(df(), is.numeric))
    cat_col <- names(dplyr::select_if(df(), is.character))
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_numeric_replace_input", choices = num_col)
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_cat_replace_input", choices = cat_col)
})

output$missing_summary <- renderTable({
    filtered_output() %>%
        mutate_all(is.na)%>%
        mutate_all(as.numeric)%>%
        summarise_all(sum)
})

observeEvent(input$confirm_numeric_replace, {
    if(input$select_numeric_replace_with == "Average"){
        #avg <- filtered_output() %>% summarise_at(vars(input$select_numeric_replace_input), mean)
        filtered_output <- filtered_output() %>% mutate_at(vars(input$select_numeric_replace_input), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .x))
        output$filtered_table <- renderDataTable(filtered_output)
    }
    if(input$select_numeric_replace_with == "Min"){ 
        filtered_output <- filtered_output() %>% mutate_at(vars(input$select_numeric_replace_input), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), min(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .x))
        output$filtered_table <- renderDataTable(filtered_output)
    }
    if(input$select_numeric_replace_with == "Max"){ 
        filtered_output <- filtered_output() %>% mutate_at(vars(input$select_numeric_replace_input), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), max(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .x))
        output$filtered_table <- renderDataTable(filtered_output)
    }
    if(input$select_numeric_replace_with == "0"){
        filtered_output <- filtered_output() %>% mutate_at(vars(input$select_numeric_replace_input), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), 0, .x))
        output$filtered_table <- renderDataTable(filtered_output)
    }


})

output$filtered_table <- renderDataTable(filtered_output())

#Closing Cleaning

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You could try using eventReactive() instead ob observeEvent.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
filtered_output <- reactive({
  if (input$select_numeric_replace_with == "Average") {
    filtered_output <- df() %>% mutate_at(vars(input$select_numeric_replace_input), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .x))
  } else if (input$select_numeric_replace_with == "Min") { 
    filtered_output <- df() %>% mutate_at(vars(input$select_numeric_replace_input), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), min(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .x))
  } else if (input$select_numeric_replace_with == "Max") {
    filtered_output <- df() %>% mutate_at(vars(input$select_numeric_replace_input), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), max(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .x))
  } else if (input$select_numeric_replace_with == "0") {
    filtered_output <- df() %>% mutate_at(vars(input$select_numeric_replace_input), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), 0, .x))
  }
  filtered_output
})

output$filtered_table <- renderDataTable(filtered_output())
```

The key point here is that `Observe()` functions should only be used when you are running a side-effect, basically anything that does not return an object (e.g. saving a plot to disk). For any situation where you are returning an object such as here, use `reactive()` instead.

I should note that your code as is seems weird even as I provided above - why use `ifelse(is.na(.x), ...` if you are returning `mean()`, `min()`, or `max()` with `na.rm = TRUE`? I would presume off-hand that the `na.rm = TRUE` argument makes the `ifelse()` all redundant. But I don't know what your data is structured like, so I can't comment further on that.